# Angular data tables sorting,searching and pagination not working?

Tags: angular8, angular-datatables

> I am Using the below data table for my angular 8
>   project(https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started).In
>   this when I am using static data it work perfectly (sorting ,searching
>   and pagination). But when I am using dynamic data for table rows the
>   above functionalities not working.I dont know what goes wrong someone
>   guide me Please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do as here:

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way

Or explain more what's your problem.